# Formatting drive before using Windows installation Media

Tags: windows-10, format, reinstall, media-creation-tool

I want to reinstall windows to start clean and I want to remove ANY files left.

I made a bootable USB using the Windows Media Creation Tool.

I am wondering if I should now format the entire drive, or if selecting the option to keep no files will provide a 100% clean install.

It's on a SSD and I want to create another partition on it. Should I do that first (in which case I should format first)? And will it be bad for my SSD to delete and rewrite everything?

Comment: What do you want to do?
Do you want to clean whole HHD/SSD?

Comment: It doesn’t matter, but if your going to do a clean installation, do yourself a favor and delete the partitions on the disk then install Windows from within the installation environment

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what windows you want to install.

Keep no files without formatting OS partition means (in XP terms) delete /Windows/ and keep everything else intact on the OS partition.

If you want to delete everything on specific partitions, just fully format all the partitions you want, or delete the whole drive and re-partition it.

This is just to make everything clean, not to make the data unrecoverable, which is another topic.

Comment: It's windows 10.

Comment: Then delete the old windows partition. W10 automatically splits it up for other needs also.